# Strange 404 error with Web API unit testing when EF DB initializer is not set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am writing unit tests for my Web API project which uses entity framework for the DB persistence and Unity for dependency resolution. All the while, I was testing with the following statement in the test assembly initialize phase:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ForceDeleteInitializer<CloudServicesDb>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CloudServicesDb>()));
```

The `ForceDeleteInitializer` is a wrapper I wrote to force delete the DB even when there are open connections. I am only adding this in my test code, and in my web API host I don't have this.

My unit tests use `HttpClient` constructed with a new `System.Web.Http.HttpServer` object which uses a `HttpConfiguration` object that is initialized with the same code that I use to initialize my web API host (in `Global.asax`)

Now I observed a strange behavior. When I removed the DB initializer in my test code, I suddenly start to see 404 errors with this message: `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://myhost/accounts'.`

I don't get any errors when I retain the DB initializer line shown above. Also, if I test this with fiddler against a web API host in IISExpress, everything works as expected. On the server side, I can't see any exceptions being thrown. My error handler filter is not invoked nor the VS debugger breaking into any breakpoints - even when I set the flag to break on the event the exception is thrown, not unhandled.

I suspect something wrong with the way how my objects are being resolved (using the Unity DI). But I am at a loss on how to debug this problem further. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I found the cause of this problem, although I can't explain why it is so.

The `Database.SetInitializer(...)` method is called in a static method with `[AssemblyInitialize]` attribute on it. I have now removed it and changed it to a singleton pattern and letting the initialization occur on the first use. And this solved my problem!

The only logical explanation that I have is that the DB initialization is taking enough time to let the assemblies in which the controllers are located to load before creating the `HttpServer` object. This is just a guess at this point.

Well - in any case, I learnt that `[AssemblyInitialize]` is not a friendly attribute to rely upon. Using a singleton pattern is simply enough.